# Ajax Call, Multiple Object Parameters, Null at Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm pulling my hair out.  I can get this to work with one object coming in but when I pass two objects in it fails.  I know it is something stupid.

Simple POCO:

```
public class Test
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GetTestAjaxCallWithMultiObjsIn([FromBody]Test input, Test inputAnother)
    {
        return  Json(string.Concat(input.FirstName, inputAnother.LastName));
    }
```

Both Input and inputAnother are null from JS

Everything from JS

```
    var input = { FirstName: 'Bart', LastName: 'Simpson' };
    var inputAnother = { FirstName: 'Bart', LastName: 'Simpson' };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetTestAjaxCallWithMultiObjsIn',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({input: input, inputAnother: inputAnother}),
        success: function (response) {
            console.dir(response);
        }
    });
```

What is wrong with the data:  stringify???

Thanks tons!

Using .NET CORE 3.1  if it matters

```
    Request Payload
    {input: {FirstName: "Bart", LastName: "Simpson"},…}
    input: {FirstName: "Bart", LastName: "Simpson"}
     inputAnother: {FirstName: "Bart", LastName: "Simpson"}
```

To be clear:  I am trying to pass to different objects in as Params

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public IActionResult GetTestAjaxCallWithMultiObjsIn(Test input, Testing inputAnother)
    {
        return  Json(string.Concat(input.FirstName, inputAnother.LastName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send multiple distinct objects and bind them to multiple different params. With `[FromBody]` the entire request body will be bound to that param. If you need to send multiple things, then you should bind to an enumerable of that thing, and send the JSON as an array of objects.

Comment: I don't need two of test, I just used that as the example.  I will be passing tow completely different objects in.  I'll try removing the [FromBody].

Comment: Then, you're completely out of luck. You misunderstood me, it's not that you can just simply remove `FromBody`, you *must* have that if you're binding something like JSON. Not optional. The point is that you only get one bite at this: one param. That's it. If you need two entirely different objects, your only option is to create another class that composes those two classes, and bind to that instead. In which case, you'd need to of course mirror this in the JSON you're sending: an object of objects.

Comment: Core changed the way model binding is implemented, this approach used to work in Framework.  Thanks for the help!!!!